# Magento 2 : How to override a Abstract Class?

Tags: magento2, overrides, abstract-class

I made some modification related to magento2 order pdf.

I want to know how to override a abstract class AbstractPdf extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject

Comment: **You Can not Rewrite Abstract Class In Magento**

Comment: then what is the solution

Comment: override the class that is using that method rather than abstract class

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149732)

Comment: Why do you want to overwrite AbstractPdf? Just overwrite the class (or classes) which are extending AbstractPdf and change the methods there.